# How to cast a void pointer to point more than one struct?

Tags: c

Having Problems about how to access other structure membera with void pointer of other  function??

```
typedef struct
{
char Buf[20];
char Str[20];
}Sample;
typedef struct
{
char Data[20];
int  i;
} Test;
```

Void pointer structure

```
typedef struct
{
void *New;
int j;
} Datastruct;


 int main()
    {
           //i am confused with first line
            Datastruct->New = &Sample;
            strcpy((( sample*)Datastruct->New )->Buf,"adam");
            printf(" Datastruct->New->Buf");
            Datastruct->New = &Test;
            strcpy((( Test*)Datastruct->New)->Data,"Eve");
            printf("Datastruct->New->Data");
            return 0;
        }
```

please let me know how to access members of other structures via void pointers

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.

Comment: FYI, this code won't compile.  At all.

Comment: *Sample* is not variable, it's type. You can't take its address

Comment: This code is completly missing any variable declartions.

Comment: Until you understand what a pointer is and what a type is, you shouldn't be mucking with void pointers.

Comment: Sure, i am working on improving my pointers

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is also confused about first line; you can't take the address of a type.  As for following void pointers, you've got the right idea: cast it to the type of pointer you wish to treat it as.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed version which actually compiles and works without errors:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char Buf[20];
  char Str[20];
} Sample;

typedef struct {
  char Data[20];
  int i;
} Test;

typedef struct {
  void *New;
  int j;
} Datastruct;

int main() {
  Datastruct d;
  Sample s;
  d.New = &s;
  strcpy(((Sample*)d.New )->Buf,"adam");
  printf("Datastruct->New->Buf\n");
  Test t;
  d.New = &t;
  strcpy(((Test*)d.New)->Data,"Eve");
  printf("Datastruct->New->Data\n");
  return 0;
}
```

In your original you were confusing `->` with `.` and types (e.g. `Datastruct`) with variables of that type.